# Is it possible to make independent modules in one xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

is it possible to create several independent modules which can be integrated into one xamarin app considering that i don't want an app which simply launches others apps already installed on the smartphone.

Goal :
One dev team takes charge of app1, one dev team takes charge of app2 and another dev team takes charge of masterApp. The MasterApp "simply" adds app1 and app2 with nuget packages for example.
App1 and app2 must be built independently of masterAPP.

Is it possible to do such a thing ?

What i tried to do :

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO1C7.png)

Comment: You are talking about the creating libraries not applications, i.e. just like adding a Nuget-based library and then your "master app" can instance the views, services, etc... from your other independently developed libraries....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial. With Xamarin you can create PCL library, that can be used on iOS/Android/WP.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/

For our specific case (black box) you can create Class Library:

1) Create class library project 
[image]

2) Write code that you need 
[image]

3) Build as Release configuration

[image]

4) Locate builded .dll

[image]

5) Add it as .Net Assemble Reference to another Project

[image]

[image]

6) Call your public methods. You won't be able to look up implementations.

[image]

Comment: Yes but i would like to share more than just portable code : an entire app in the form of libraries with some specific code (android views, iOS views for example). 

Look at my question, i add an image.

Comment: Then I can suggest you to create Class Library. Screen shot (http://nn.lv/z2sx) It will behave like iOS/Android Xamarin library. You can call platform specific methods, and show your custom UI from it in another projects. I wasnt able to find any tutorial about it related to Xamarin, but there is plenty of them for iOS native.

Comment: Yes, it's working, I can start an activity in the android class library of app1 from masterApp, but the master app knows App1 implementation. App1 must be a "black box". Please tell me if my explanation is not clear.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you dedicated to me, it became clearer to me now :) I have one last question : in my android class library, i add the nuget package "mvvmcross" for data binding for my android views. Now when i build my masterApp which contains my android class library, i have errors because masterApp needs mvvmcross too. Have i missed something ?

Comment: @PierreL Yes, you need to reference dependency library (of your library) in root application. You'r welcome, you can mark my answer as correct if it worked :)

Comment: Ok :) So i can't really have completely independents app1 and app2 in my masterApp. By contrast, is it possible for masterApp team to have a single point of entry for lauching app1 and then, app1 (which is done of pcl, android and ios class library and not with a classi blank app xamarin) can live his life alone ? :)

Comment: @PierreL Well.. actually you can. You need to fully download dependent library to drive, then hard link it to your library, and compile your library with dependent library inside (not as reference, but as real .dll file in project).